# How do I use the Weka API to ask for inputs to single attributes to traverse a decision tree?

Tags: java, weka, decision-tree

I have scoured the internet but was unable to find a way to implement the following functionality using the tools in the Weka API to access the tree nodes.

I use the Weka API to create a J48 decision tree. I want to be able to ask the user to input an option for the root of the tree. For example, I used the "labor.arff" training file to get the following tree and want to as the user for an input based on the circled node.

[image: First question to user.]

Let's say, for example, the user inputs "3" to answer this question. The tree should then process this input and traverse the tree to the right.

[image: Process input and traverse to right.]

The user would then be given a prompt for the response to the next node, in this case "statutory-holidays". To which the user may respond "6". This input would be processed and the left branch of the tree would be traversed.

[image: Prompt for second node, request and process second input.]

The program would then detect that the node it is at is a leaf-node and print out the classification.

[image: Leaf-Node! Classified!]

This is all being implemented in the command-line in Java.

Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could have Weka build your J48 decision tree and then output the source code.  Once you have the source code you could modify it to fit your needs!  An example of outputting the source code and modifying it is shown in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278386/weka-predict-classifcation-node/19286903#19286903).

However, if the decision tree is going to change frequently, this might not be the best option.  A good option may be to take input from the user to create their own instance and classify that.   Unfortunately with that route you may end up asking more questions than required to traverse the tree.

Comment: Thank you, Walter for your reply! Unfortunately, my program has to take in a variety of trees on the fly and also has to ask correct number of questions... I have tried to modify the API to be able to get the root element of the tree. Do you think this could be useful?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.  I don't have any experience modifying the API, but if you are going to modify something, why not look into modify the interface that outputs the source code?  This is the ["sourceable interface"](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/classifiers/Sourcable.html).  Would it be possible to use that to output an object that does what you ask?