# Traversing weka J48 tree

Tags: java, weka

I built a database and the J48 tree using the Weka API. I wanted to know if there is a way to traverse the tree in real time (like asking the input from a user) until a leaf is reached in order to classify the given istance (without asking to the user all the values of the attributes)

I'm doing this for a videogame. I tried looking on the web for some information and I couldn't find anything. Also all the methods in the J48 class doesn't seem to do what I'm looking for.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could have Weka build your J48 decision tree and then output the source code. Once you have the source code you could modify it to fit your needs! An example of outputting the source code and modifying it is shown in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278386/weka-predict-classifcation-node/19286903#19286903).

However, if the decision tree is going to change frequently, this might not be the best option. A good option may be to take input from the user to create their own instance and classify that. Unfortunately with that route you may end up asking more questions than required to traverse the tree.

Comment: the problem is that the tree will change really often. Also I need to ask as few questions as I can :(